# Why can't I delete an item(in this case a java tar.gz) file of usb live boot for Xubuntu 12.10?

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, delete, trash

I am booting Xubuntu 12.10 off a live usb and cannot delete a tar.gz file, every time i try to delete the file it says it cannot find or create the trash directory :( is there anyway to fix this so i can free up space on my usb? Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure the file does not belong to Xubuntu. You are booting from USB and trying to delete files from USB?
2. Try deleting with Shift + Del. It deletes directly without moving things to trash (which is apparently missing).
3. Try deleting from the commandline (If that doesn't work, post the error message that appears).